# PHImageManager throws "First stage of an opportunistic image request returned a non-table format image, this is not fatal, but it is unexpected"

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phasset, photosframework

I am using PHImageCachingManager to get images for PHAsset. I need to use the `opportunistic` mode so that first the low resolution image available gets loaded and then as the full resolution becomes available, it gets loaded.

For some reason I keep getting the following warning and my low resolution image doesn't load. Image only loads when the highest resolution gets fetched (from iCloud).

The warning:

```
"First stage of an opportunistic image request returned a non-table format image, this is not fatal, but it is unexpected."
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    imageRequestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    imageRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
    let imageCachingManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    imageCachingManager.requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: imageRequestOptions) { (image, infoDict) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.myImageView.identifierTag == asset.localIdentifier {
                self.myImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
imageCachingManager.requestImage(for: asset , targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: imageRequestOptions) { (image, infoDict) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.myImageView.identifierTag == asset.localIdentifier {
            self.myImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

You are setting the maximum size available as an image size.  Change

```
targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize
```

to

```
targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
```

or specify the image size like CGSize(with: 150, height: 150) unless you want to explode your device due to memory depletion.

Comment: What's the difference between using `asset.pixelWidth` method vs PHImageManagerMaximumSize? Also wouldn't it just be a bug then if using `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` doesn't allow opportunistic viewing? I looked at the memory being used and it's not that bad.

Comment: Are you saying that you still see the warning with `targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)`?

Comment: No I don't see the warning if I use that. But I am curious wouldn't that mean PHImageManagerMaximumSize is useless for `.opportunistic`? Aka a bug?

Comment: I don't know the exact difference.  If you compare PHImageManagerMaximumSize and asset.size, the latter is consistently smaller with a fixed width.

Answer (score -1):

```
PHImageRequestOptions *option = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
option.synchronous = YES;
``
将synchronous 属性设置为YES
```